# Add a specific string at the end of each line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a mainfile with 4 columns, such as:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
```

in another file, i have one line of text corresponding to the respective line in the mainfile, which i want to add as a new column to the mainfile, such as:

```
a b c d x
e f g h y
i j k l z
```

Is this possible in bash? I can only add the same string to the end of each line.

Comment: Take a look at `man paste`

Comment: That works just fine, so easy!

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you can do

1) `paste file1 file2`

2) Iterate over both files and combine line by line and write to new file

Answer (score 1):

You could use GNU parallel for that:

```
fe-laptop-m:test fe$ cat first 
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
fe-laptop-m:test fe$ cat second 
x
y
z
fe-laptop-m:test fe$ parallel echo  ::::+ first second 
a b c d x
e f g h y
i j k l z
```

Do I get you right what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#(^.*) .*#/^\1/s/$/ &/#' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Create a sed script from file2 that uses a regexp to match a line in file1 and if it does appends the contents of that line in file2 to the matched line.

N.B.This is independent of the order and length of file1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `pr`

```
pr -mts' ' file1 file2
```